# scrollToRowAtIndexPath not calling cellForRowAtIndexPath and not scrolling UITable view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios5

Actually I need to make pdf file for all transaction in my project. So I creating PDFViewController Class with .xib that contains uiView,uitableView,etc.

I am not displying this class to user, interally I am taking screen shots of this class view to make pdf for all transactions.

My problem is that I can take screen shot view and table but I have lot of rows in table so I need to scroll it to take screen shot only for tableview but its not scrolling.

please see the below code any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
@implementation PDFViewController

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"PDFCustomCell";
    PDFViewCustomCell *cell=(PDFViewCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) 
    {
        NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"PDFViewCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        nib=nil;
    }

    //@autoreleasepool {

    PDFPrint *pdfObj=[self.arrProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.unitPrice.text=[currencyFormator stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[pdfObj.unitPrice doubleValue]]];
    UIImage* img =  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/downloads/%@/files/%@.jpg",del.LocalPath,del.CompFolder,del.RepId,pdfObj.code]];
    if(img!=nil)
        [cell.imageView setImage:img];
    else
        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_privew95x77.jpg"]];
        pdfObj=nil;
            return cell;
    //}
}
```

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
  NSLog(@"Array Count is = %i",[self.arrProducts count]);
  return [self.arrProducts count];
  }

  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
    return 1;
    }
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString* strlogopath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",del.LocalPath,del.CompFolder,del.CompInfo.ImageName];
    [self.imgLogo setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:strlogopath]];
    strlogopath = nil;
    [self filldata];

  }
  -(void)filldata
  {
     //here I am filling Data from many tables in arrProduct NSMutableArray I have removed number of lines for StackOverflow for code complexity. I am getting Data in arrProduct accurately.

  ```
          [self.arrProducts addObject:pdfData];


      [SQLHelper finalizeStatement:stmt];
  }
  @catch (NSException *exception)
  {
      NSLog(@"%@",exception.description);
  }
  @finally 
  {
      [SQLHelper disconnectDB:database];
  }
  ```

  }

  @end

  //  CurrentTransaction.m
  // in the currentTransaction.m I am not adding the self.pdfViewController view bcoz I don't need to show it. I have to take screen shot only then need to make pdf file
  the problem is I can't scroll table to take next rows screen shot.

  - (UIView *)loadTemplate:(PrintChoice_t)type
    {
    if (type==Small_Photo)
    {
        self.pdfViewController=[[PDFViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PDFViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] ReferenceController:& self];
    }
    return self.pdfViewController.view;
    }

  //someWhere in this class I am calling

  [self.pdfViewController.tblProd scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:14 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];

  //But scrollToRowAtIndexPath not calling CellForRowAtIndexPath in PDFViewController. I can see debug info only 14 rows visible 0 location 14 rows.

Comment: pleaseUseCamelCaps properly in your title. Those all-lowercase method names are extremely hard to read.

Comment: Why I got down vote? can you plz tell me

Comment: if you cant answer me then its not fare to downvote it? can anyone tell me why i got loses tow reputation :(:(:(:(:(

Comment: I didn't downvote you. But I can probably explain why you got the downvote. The reason is **not** that people cannot answer your question. The reson is the low quality of the question - you bumped a whole wall of code into the editor which is not quite relevant to the problem you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the table in another view controller (pdfViewController from CurrentTransaction view controller), yet you are passing as an indexpath the CurrentTransaction view indexPath, which will be either nil, if your CurrentTransaction view doesn't have a tableView or if the TableView has not 14 rows, or it will have a non valid NSIndexPath.

I would suggest adding a custom public method in your pdfViewController, that will scroll to the row. Something like this:

```
- (void)scrollToRow:(int)row atSection:(int)section {
     [self.tblProd scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:14 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO]
}
```

Then in CurrentTransaction.m replace

```
[self.pdfViewController.tblProd scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:14 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
```

with:

```
[self.pdfViewController scrollToRow:14 atSection:0];
```

Should work fine then!

Comment: Still UiTableView not scrolling:( Thanks for you time. actually indexPath is not nil in both ways and pdfViewController also not nil.cellForRowAtIndexPath not calling. Since Morning I am unable to solve this issue

Comment: Is the table initially drawn correctly? When you reload it I mean? Else it means that your view is not set as the tables delegate and (possibly datasource too) you need to set it.

Comment: Thanks for you Time, Table is drawn correctly I can see it in screen shot all thing is working perfect I got data from Sqlite in to tableview like images and other stuff. But I can't scroll it to next rows to take screen shot. Tableview initially shows only 13 rows only.

Comment: well if your table doesn't have 14 rows, you can't scroll to the 14th row obviously. Check if you are providing the correct data to the table and you are returning the correct number in the numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: No I have 25 five row for one transaction

Comment: Normally you call scrollToRowAtIndexPath cellForRowAtIndexPath called but it never call it. I don't think where is issue

Comment: I don't see you providing in your pdfViewController.m file the **required** `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` datasource method.....

Comment: I am providing numberOfRowsInSection someone suggest me to not dumped a lot of code on SO that's why I reduces some lines